# ngClass issue in angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I'm developing a site in angular 1.5, in order to make it on angular 2, when stable.

I have this code:

```
<li ng-class="day==1 ? a : b" ng-repeat="day in $ctrl.daysMap">
    {{day}}
</li>
```

the `ng-repeat` is being repeating the `li` correctly.
Now I need for every `li` created to add class to that `li`, depending on the current position of `daysMap`.

I though the ng-class like above should work, but neither class is added to the `li`, instead of that, the `ng-class` is showed in the html, but no class is added

Comment: I think you need to write `ng-class="day==1 ? 'a' : 'b'"`

Comment: Try something like ng-class="{'a': day == 1, 'b': day != 1}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work if a and b where valid $scope properties. If they were strings, it needs to look like this:

```
ng-class="day==1 ? 'a' : 'b'"
```